# How to get id logout usde

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using laravel 5.8 my question is how to get logout user id because I print logout user data on home page.

```
 public function userLogin()
    {
   
        return view('frontend.user-login');
    }
```

Comment: Berfore logout `$id = Auth::user()->id;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, here `user` contains the data from your user table :

```
public function userLogin()
{
  $user = Auth::user();
  // logout here
  // Auth::logout();
  // Session::flush();
  return view('frontend.user-login', compact('user'));
}
```

In your blade you can get the data like this :

```
@if(!empty($user)) {{ $user->id }} @endif
@if(!empty($user)) {{ $user->email }} @endif
```